# Android Studio Unable to run AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, hypervisor

I am getting below error:

> emulator: ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between
>   HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple
>   hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find
>   out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and
>   https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox) Internal error:
>   initial hax sync failed

While it say work is under going, I can run studio on my collegue's machine with same OS(WIN 7), and same machine specs.

Is there a work around this issue currently ?

Comment: Did you read those issues? Are you using Docker for Windows or tried to downgrade your Virtualbox to pre 4.3.30?

Comment: I don't have virtual box in my machine, and I had downloaded virtualbox version 4.0.6 and installed. But error stayed same, and AVD didn't start.

Comment: If you are sure you don't have Virtualbox, then I am not sure what that error is saying. Personally, I use Genymotion as my emulator, and it runs just as well as the HAXM one.

Comment: Thanks a lots [cricket-007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) , It's good catch. Whole days wasted by me regarding to the issue.

Answer (score 140):

I received the follow error:

> ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between HAXM
>   hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple
>   hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find
>   out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and
>   https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox)

**To solve this problem I only needed to close Docker on Mac.**

Comment: Yeah. It worked for me like this last week. This morning, I uninstalled docker and and virtualbox and then installed just docker for mac. And then after quiting Docker, it's still happening

Comment: Closing Docker on mac may not be sufficient though: I had a docker-machine running by default so I had to stop it manually.  run "docker-machine ls" and then "docker-machine stop xxx" to stop all the running machines

Comment: yes yes yes, do not forget to `docker-machine stop` on your host before running an Android emulator

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem. While researching I found out about this https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-using-docker-for-mac-with-android-emulator-haxm/8939/3

Apparently, Docker and Android emulators using HAXM cannot run together. I had Docker running in my system. I stopped it and the emulator was able to run without a problem.

If you have Docker installed and running, stop it and try again.

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to emulate an Ionic 1 app on an Android emulator with `ionic emulate android -lcs` and encountered the same error:

`emulator: ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox)
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Internal error: initial hax sync failed`

I solved it by saving and suspending execution of all other running VMs with the following steps:

1) Quit Docker for Mac by clicking the whale icon in the top bar and selecting "Quit Docker". I believe this is required because the Docker Daemon (server) of Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox automatically runs in a Linux VM when the Docker Client is running (you do not need to and cannot run it manually with `dockerd` or `docker daemon`). The Docker Client is running when the whale icon is in the top bar.

2) Stop all Vagrant VMs running on the host machine by running `vagrant halt`, as they may be using Virtual Box as the provider. Check their state changes to Powered Off by running `vagrant status`.

3) Stop all Virtual Box VMs by running `virtualbox` to open Virtual Box GUI and then Right-click any VMs and select Close > Save State

4) Close and re-open your Terminal window before retrying

Comment: I like this answer because it covers more than just Docker. In my case I had a vagrant box which I'd forgotten about.

Comment: The part 4) was the winner for me :)

Answer (score 11):

I simply stopped running Docker on Mac.
The emulator then was able to run properly.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have two emulators that are trying to use the same resources on the computer i.e. both the Google one and the Genymotion (VirtualBox) one.  Who knows how long/if that will be addressed.  If you are running Genymotion you use VirtualBox.  So, try to run the Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager and check that no virtual machines are running and shut down any that are.  You should be able to run emulators in studio again, just make sure you pick one (Genymotion) or the other (Android AVD manager).

Comment: I had this problem on my Mac so I opened up VirtualBox, closed the emulator I had running and then the Android AVD manager emulator worked again

Answer (score 2):

There was [an update](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-using-docker-for-mac-with-android-emulator-haxm/8939/11) on the thread that [Mehmed found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142955/1386766) It is not necessary to stop Docker. If you have run all the Android Studio updates, you have the Intel installer already downloaded at Users/your_user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_6.1.1.dmg. You need to run the installer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and I did the following:

1) Stopped the Docker for mac (Quit)
2) I use 2 monitor (One Mac Screen + Extended another screen), I disconnected the second monitor and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (macOS), stop/quit docker does not help. I need to run `boot2docker poweroff`.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you don't have more that one Virtual Machine running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows Users:

1. Close all open emulators.
2. Open Task Manager.
3. **End Process:** All instances of **adb.exe**.
4. **End Process:** All processes which has **Virtual Box** or **VBox...** in Description.
5. Restart Emulator.