# incompatibility between HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I hope most of you facing this, I searched all over internet and couldn't find possible solution for this.

I am totally wasting my time researching on this and finally landed here for your help.

I am using Android studio 2.1.2 on windows 10 x64bit machine and android studio emulator is not running at all. Below is the console message.

```
C:\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_6_API_22
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox)
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Internal error: initial hax sync failed
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Related discussion: [Android Studio Unable to run AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397810/android-studio-unable-to-run-avd)