# Waiting for Target Device to Come Online

Tags: android, timeout, emulation

I recently updated to Android Studio 2.3, and now when I try to run the application, the emulator does not come online. It times out after 300 seconds.

Additionally, The app has been experiencing a FATAL EXCEPTION ERROR (OOM), and I am not sure how to fix that either, or if that is part of the emulator problem.

Any help is much appreciated. Again, my knowledge in the program is very limited so if your answer can be kept simple, that would be great.

Comment: this is occuring for me also after the update.  adb keeps saying the device is offline. i think its a studio bug. switching to genymotion emulator resolves my issues.

Comment: I'm getting this issue with real devices, no emulator. Android Studio 4.2.2 , Platform-tools up to date

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I too had the same problem, then I went to AVD manager and right click on the emulator and stopped it and I RUN the application again and this time it worked.
It may be a temporary solution but works for the time being.

> Tools -> AVD manager -> right-click on the emulator you are using -> Stop

Now `Run` your application again.

Note: Sometimes closing the emulator directly is not working for the above-mentioned problem but stopping it from the AVD manager as mentioned is working.

Comment: Seems as if there was a problem with the emulator. This worked! Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about Android Studio 2.3.1, but when this problem encountered for the first time in 2.3.0 this solution worked.  I never encountered the same problem in 2.3.1

Comment: I think this might accidentally work at fixing the race condition, but the real 100% solution is MarkDubya's below.

Comment: I have same problem and following the steps did not help it resolve yet

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction but what helped was using the "Cold boot" option from AVD Manager.

Comment: Cold boot helped!

Comment: even cold boot doesn't help more :(

Comment: `adb kill-server` (after you closed the emulators) could help

Answer (score 202):

**Following worked for me on Android Studio 3.x.**

**Step 1:** 
Open AVD Manager.

[image]

**Step 2:**
Right click and Wipe data for the virtual device you're testing on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked. Probably some files that weren't updating properly on the emulator.

Comment: Worked for me with AS 2.3.3 and Nexus 5X

Comment: Thanks buddy :) Works like a charm.

Had anyone reported this to Google Developers?

Comment: I ended up creating a new emulator (needed to anyway for screen size) and deleting the old one.  That fixed it as well.

Comment: Worked for me in Android Studio 3.5.3

Comment: So far the best solution for me. Just all the stored data are wiped but finally it is working

Comment: This worked for me right away. I'm using the latest version of Android Studio as of this writing.

Comment: Worked very well. Note that AVD Manager is now called Device Manager, and instead of right-clicking the device you have to click the downwards arrow to the right under "Actions" to find the "Wipe Data" option.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 59):

In case you are on Mac, ensure that you exit Docker for Mac. This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Genius!! saves lot of time ... kudos!

Comment: What is a Docker for Mac?

Comment: always docker!~

Comment: Can someone please explain how to exit Docker for Mac?

Comment: Why is Docker causing a problem with the emulator in this case? This works for me but I want to know why Docker conflicts with the emulator?

Comment: This would be helpful if there was instructions on exiting the "Docker" on a Mac??

Comment: Docker is a virtualization tool, like the Android emulator, but it is more aimed at lightweight systems, I believe controlled only by command line, it is more used by backend and infrastructure professionals

Answer (score 30):

Three days on this, and I believe there's a race condition between adb and the emulator. On a request to run an app, with no emulator already running, you see the "Initializing ADB", then the emulator choice, it starts and you get "Waiting for target to come online". An adb kill-server, or a kill -9, or an "End Process" of adb with the task manager will cause adb to die, restart, your APK installs and you're good to go. It does seem funky to me that an "adb kill-server" causes adb to die and then restart here, but that's another mystery, maybe.

Comment: Thank you for tracking this down. This absolutely worked for me with Android Studio 2.3.1

Comment: 2.3.1 on windows 10, killing the adb.exe process so it restarts appears to resolve the issue for me too. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the answer. The selected answer didn't work for me, but this does every time. Thanks!

Comment: In the terminal type: cd to change directory to: android > sdk  >platform-tools. Then type: 'adb kill-server'. and then: 'adb start-server'

Comment: On AS v 2.3.3, this proposed solution did not work. I ran `adb kill-server` from terminal. The `waiting for target device...` message was not stopped and the server did not restart. I still don't have a solution.

Comment: @MikeS.I had same issue as you but then I restarted Android Studio after doing MarkDubya suggestion

Comment: Still applies to Android Studio 3.1.4.  Come on, Google!  This is pretty important stuff to get right!

Comment: Happened today with Android Studio 4.1.0 and all my AVDs. The solutions described in the other answers (`Wipe Data` or `Cold Boot`) didn't help. At first I didn't found this answer and wanted to go to the `adb logcat` route. This is only afterwards that I found this answer which proved I was right in the good direction ^^

Answer (score 26):

1. Another case is Android **Emulator should be reinstalled**. This can happen, when you install a higher version of Android Studio, then update SDK for it, and go back to previous one.

   > Tools - Android - SDK Manager - SDK Tools - Android Emulator -
   >   uncheck, apply, check, apply
2. **Disable Docker** app if you have it (Mac users).
3. **Restart emulator**:

   > Tools - Android - AVD Manager
   >   (or kill adb process in task manager).

Comment: The Emulator wasn't even installed in my case.

Comment: Nice, this one helped me out!

Comment: I tried this option as well however the problem is still there.

Comment: In my case the Android SDK Platform was only partially installed.

Comment: docker was the reason in my case! thanks!

Comment: Or just updated.  Following step 1 here, I noticed that all the tools I had installed had updates available.  Once I installed the updates, my emulators came online.

Answer (score 18):

Go to **AVD Manager** in your Android Studio.**Right Click on your emulator**,and then **select wipe data**.Then **run your app again**.
The emulator will perform a clean boot and then install your apk then your app will finally run.

*Summary*:**AVD Manager---Right Click Emulator----Wipe Data----Run App Again**

If the problem presists,then simply go back to your avd manager ,**uninstall emulator**,then **add a new emulator**.Once the new emulator is added,in your avd manager,run the emulator...Then run your app.
*Its much simpler if you have an emulator already running from the onset before running your application for the first time*

Comment: Only after uninstall/reinstall did it work for me.

Answer (score 17):

After trying all these solutions without success the one that fixed my problem was simply changing the Graphics configuration for the virtual device from Auto to Software (tried hardware first without success)

Comment: Where is this virtual device Graphic Configuration?

Comment: @stramin Go to Android Virtual Device Manager (from Tools menu), click Edit (pen icon) on your virtual machine, find the Graphics option there. :)

Answer (score 11):

This solution works for me :
Tools -> AVD Manager -> click drop down arrow -> select `Cold Boot Now`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Seems like Android Studio (using version 3.5.1) gets into a weird state after a while. This worked for me.

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 8):

Below steps work for me

1. Close running emulator
2. Go to AVD Manager
3. Choose available emulator
4. In that action tab (last one), click on drop down arrow & select COLD BOOT NOW
5. Finally run your application

Comment: The cold boot was enough for me.

Answer (score 8):

Go to **AVD Manager** right click on your device and select **Wipe Data** and **Cold Boot Now**.
For me it worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd add one more step: Stop before ColdBoot Now. After that, you can run the application without stopping the device.

Answer (score 5):

After trying almost all the solutions listed above, what finally worked for me was to create a new virtual device using a "Google APIs" image instead of a "Google Play" image.

Comment: This must be selected as the correct answer. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Seems that in my case the problem was in that the "Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image" wasn't automatically installed during installation of Android Studio.

After installing the image, the emulator began to work.

[Screenshot of the SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dho34.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Did not read all the answers. Anyway Accepted one didn't work for me. What did was upgrading the android studio to last stable version and then created a new virtual device. I guess my nexus 5p virtual device got out of sync with the android studio environment.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Android studio 4+ and Mac OS

1. Delete all AVD's that you currently have.
2. Go to Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings >
   Android SDK > SDK Tools
3. Uninstall Android Emulator
4. Restart Android Studio.
5. Re-install Android Emulator from the same place.
6. Create a new emulator!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that having a running instance of Docker on my machine (OSX) prevented the Android Emulator from running (see [Android Studio Unable to run AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397810/android-studio-unable-to-run-avd/39142955))

Previously, my emulator would appear to start, then fail before any device window was shown.

I also had to use 'kill -9' (as per @MarkDubya ) to get Android Studio to connect to the virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

Like [urupvog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515962/539149), make sure that you **aren't running any other virtual machines like VirtualBox**.  When I restarted my computer, AVD worked until I started Vagrant for backend development (then it wouldn't launch).

See [Android emulator and virtualbox cannot run at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168799/android-emulator-and-virtualbox-cannot-run-at-same-time) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have the deviced unauthorized, unauthorized devices reply the same error in the Android Studio, check the emulator once is on with the adb command.

$ adb devices

List of devices attached

emulator-5554   unauthorized

If you have of this way the emulator the Android Studio is waiting for be authorized and maybe this can solve the problem.

[Authorized Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)

This is a error I have solved in Windows 10 with Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Please read  [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ? Ur just referring another question.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for this issue is simple :

- Go to SDK tools > SDK Tools
- Check Android Emulator and click Apply

and sometimes you might see there's an update available next to it, you just need to let it finish the update

Answer (score 1):

For those stuck on this problem on a device and not the emulator, make sure your app isn't set as the device owner.

Comment: How do you change that?

Comment: adb shell dpm remove-active-admin package.name/MyDeviceAdminReceiver

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128293/how-to-remove-set-device-owner-in-android-dpm

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have to instances of Android Studio that both use the same device, which seems to corrupt it irretrievably.
Delete the device and create a new one.
Thereafter, create new devices and always use different devices in different sessions.
Oh, and remember to switch the Logcat window to the new device.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too old but may be helpful to someone in future.
After search many things, most of them is not worked for me. SO, as per my try This solution is worked for me. In short uninstall and install "Android SDK Tools" in Android SDK.

Few steps for that are below:-

1. go to "SDK Manager" in Android Studio
2. go to "SDK Tools" tab
3. Uninstall "Android SDK Tools" (means remove check(uncheck) ahead of "Android SDK Tools" and Apply then OK)
4. Close and Restart Android Studio
5. Install "Android SDK Tools" (means check ahead of "Android SDK Tools" and Apply then OK)

[Image of Uninstall and Install Android SDK Tools again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUMe.jpg)

Comment: this question is neither old nor does your answer solve the problem for me ^^ I uninstalled whole Android Studio, all SDK tools and stuff, reinstalled... doesn't change.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Then may be you have problem with virtualbox (means virtual machine). Find solution for that. Best of luck!! Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no link between ide and the emulator.

In our case - we **lowered version of android** for the app, that **frustrated ide**  in emulator linking.

If we install Android 25 and bind project to it, and AVD Device on Android 25 as well - it links and apllies changes on the fly. If we downgrade to Android 14 and device on android 14 - it doesn't.

Used Android Studio 2.3.

To play with versions you can set in Gradle Scripts - build.gradle (Module: app):

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
  }
}
```

As a result app won't run on an Android 25 device with a message:

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : -26:
>   Package ru.asv.test new target SDK 15 doesn't support runtime
>   permissions but the old target SDK 25 does.. It is possible that this
>   issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it
>   is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and probably found the solution that may help. The key is launching the AVD in the emulator first then run your App.

Following are the steps:

1. In the Your Virtual Devices screen, select the device you just created and click Launch this AVD in the emulator
2. Once the emulator is booted up, click the app module in the Project window and then select Run → Run
3. In the Select Deployment Target window, select the emulator and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users using KVM and facing this problem try setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to `Software` instead of `Automatic` or `Hardware` . As previously mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41430226/3760520).

I can confirm that the method works for Arch Linux, Ubuntu 16.04, as well as windows with or without a proprietary graphics card using Android Studio version 2.3.1+

Comment: thx. it works for me. got is working by setting hw.gpu.mode = host in config.ini file

Answer (score 0):

I am working on notebook, Windows 8. I solved this issue change mode from battery saving mode to balanced mode. Before that, an emulator didn't work and I see "Target Device to Come Online". Also didn't work Genymotion

Comment: Hi Delphian can mention where can i change the battery saving mode to balanced mode

Comment: On your notebook in the lower right corner there is a battery icon, you need to click on it and check what your energy saving mode is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when updated my android studio. Somehow it changed my SDK path. I just changed it to my updated SDK path and it worked.

Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK

Here you will find Android SDK location just click on edit link in front of that and browse and select the Android SDK from the file browser. Select and click on Apply.

Select AVD manager and start Emulator. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type `android avd`. Select your AVD and select "Edit". Make sure you do not see `No CPU/ABI system image available for this target` - it will show in red font at the bottom. Change the `target` to the one that is available or download the ABI image. Sometimes, if you create an AVD from inside Android Studio, it does not ensure this requirement.

[image: AVD error]

Answer (score 0):

None of solutions above worked for me, so I had to wipe content of

```
C:\Users\your_name\.android\avd
```

and re-create emulated device

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (AVD not coming online) in a Linux system. In my case, I have solved it setting this environment variable:

```
$ export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS = 1
```

This case is documented here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html#studio_jdk

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve this problem by setting the right export path in bash file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue twice and tried everything in this thread with no results, I finally fixed it closing "BlueStacks" emulator.

If BlueStacks (and maybe others android emulators) are running when I run the app, by default Android Studio installs the app there, even when I never selected it as a device in AVD Manager, then Android Studio waits for an incorrect device "to come online".

[image]

Closing BlueStacks (or any other Android emulator) solved the conflict between devices for me.

I hope this info helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Once again, please wait for a while, sometimes you missed that it actually worked but you are feeling really stressed and could not wait(I was).

Not sure why I fixed the same issue that happened on my Macbook, however, choose Nexus 5X API R would work somehow. OR below

1. Wipe Data: Tools->Open AVD Manager and click ▼ the emu "Wipe Data"
2. Cold Boots Now: Tools->Open AVD Manager and click ▼ the emu "Cold Boots Now"
3. Uninstall & Reinstall Android Emulator from SDK: Tools->Open SDK Manager->Android SDK(left-side menu)->SDK tools(middle in the main screen), then click "Android Emulator" and APPLY, then again click "Android Emulator" apply to reinstall, so finish

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you haven't solved it yet ... the class name uses accented letters ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I first tried to run an Android application on a new MacBook Pro with M1 chip. None of the so far suggested options worked for me.

I followed the instructions in [this Medium post by Elye](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/m1-android-emulator-not-detected-workaround-c7718f08ba99), which (referring to [this Stack Overflow answer by @AndrewPK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261231/4751173)) suggested to download an older version of the Android S system images. The target locations suggested in the blog posts are wrong, but (after finding the correct ones, they're not hard to guess) I noticed the ones in the Stack Overflow answer *are* correct:

> [Google Play ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 2)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a-S_r02-darwin.zip)
>
> [Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 2)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/arm64-v8a-S_r02.zip)
>
> [T]he directory you want to put the unzipped images in is probably something like `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S`.
>
> For example, the path for the Google Play image is `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a`

Answer (score 0):

in my case (i using Pixel 3 Emulator with playstore installed)

1. i tried to run the app on real device (if its ok proceed to next step)
2. i created new device with no playstore installed (ex : Pixel 2 XL)
   It works in my case

Answer (score 0):

All the answers say the same thing, but I found out that this error happens sometimes when the `targetSdkVersion` is not the same version of the emulator. As soon as I increased the version, the problem stopped.

Answer (score 0):

if you have issues on your device (not emulator) you have to remove active admin using this:

```
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin package.name/MyDeviceAdminReceiver
```

in order to set device admin again you can use this:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner package.name/MyDeviceAdminReceiver
```

(do not forget to add C:\Users<current user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools path to your environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

I went to "AndroidManifest.xml"

and changed

android:exported -> false to **true** and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an **Asus ROG** laptop, **remove or close the GameFirst software**. I'm finally able to use Android Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your current emulator and creating a new one.

I also encountered the same problem and what’s strange is that even rebooting and clearing the emulator via wipe data didn’t help me. Then I decided to delete the current emulator and create a new one and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem as you, android studio said I had Emulator 25.3.1 already installed

I deleted the Emulator folder (it's inside the SDK folder)

And then reinstalled Emulator 25.3.1
Sdk manager--> SDKtools --> instal the emulator 25.3.1

This time it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Run/Debug configuration -> General tab

Select blank device in Prefer Android Virtual Device combo box

Now every time when you run the app, it will run on the device already open. If no Device is running, it will throw error

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have enabled USB debugging on your device

---

Depending on the version of Android you're using, proceed as follows:

- On Android 8.0 and higher, go to **Settings** > **System** > **About
  phone** and    tap **Build number** seven times.
- On Android 4.2 through 7.1.2, go to **Settings** > **About phone** and tap
  **Build number** seven times.

Return to the main **Settings** menu to find **Developer options** at the bottom. In the Developer options menu, scroll down and enable **USB debugging**.

Comment: That makes no sense since it won't see the device. Thus that wouldn't resolve the issue. The IDE Android Studio etc. is able to see the device before running the project. The issue shows up whist wanting to install and run the project on tageted device.

Answer (score -3):

Tools - Android - Sdk manager -
tab Sdk tools -
install emulator 25.3.1

Comment: Problem is after installing emulator

Answer (score -5):

Go to the Sdk manager-->  SDKtools  --> instal the emulator 25.3.1

Comment: This looks like a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42816186).