# Android Studio Waiting for Target Device to Come Online Linux Mint 18

Tags: java, android, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm running android studio on linux mint cinnamon 18, when running the app the emulator opens up and works but the app won't open and android studio keeps saying waiting for target device to come online until it times out,
any one know how to get the app running on the avd? I can get it working on my actual device, 
Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online

Comment: Hi, I've already have had a look at a lot of these posts and none of them have the same issue as me, tried all their suggestions too and it hasn't worked, thinking of doing a fresh install of android-studio

Comment: it is mainly caused due to low ram and old processors.

Comment: have you compare minSdkVersion  with you avd device? Is it support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, android-studio was using api 25 and i was running api 24, so when running the emulator it would only search for 24 (the api i had chosen on the phone)