# waiting for target device to come online Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I am running android studio 2.3.3 on ubuntu Gnome 17.04 when running the android app on the emulator it gives timeout error after "waiting for target device to come online", Actually the emulator doesn't start even when trying to start it alone from the AVD manager. I tried all the solutions in the following links but still not working.

[Waiting for Target Device to Come Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online)

[Android Studio Waiting for Target Device to Come Online Linux Mint 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201542/android-studio-waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online-linux-mint-18)

[Android Studio Waiting for Target Device to Come Online Linux Mint 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201542/android-studio-waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online-linux-mint-18)

Note: The app is working on a physical device 
Here are some screenshots from android studio:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator now starts and the problem was solved by locating lib64 folder since i am running ubuntu 64 bit. In my case, its located under ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64. Then run the following commands in terminal :

// Double Check to see if these are available

$ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386

$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

// Navigate to the ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64 folder

$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak

$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++

Source: [How can I get more information about "Waiting for target device to come online" in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612468/how-can-i-get-more-information-about-waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new AVD with different API and also use the recommended ones for better support for API's .
Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Using android studio on W10 had the same problem with the emulator tried all of the answers on StackOverflow: none worked for me until was playing with settings on Emulator, problem was because of OpenGL

Fix: the "More" button on emulator ----> Setting ----> Advanced

1- OpenGL ES Renderer: scroll to select Desktop Native OpenGL.

2- OpenGL ES API Level: scroll to select Compatibility OpenGL.

Comment: Please format your answer properly so that fellow users can understand it