# "Waiting for android device to come online" Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have updated my Android Studio to V3.0 and I have Android Emulator (Nexus 5x API 26 X86) already installed on it. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: you have Android Studio 3.0 instead of 2.3 but did you try the steps here? are you on PC or mac? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online

Comment: 1. Restart emulator 2 . Another case is Android Emulator should be reinstalled. This can happen, when you install a higher version of Android Studio, then update SDK for it, and go back to previous one.

Comment: @antonino I am on Windows. I tried but things didn't work out. Is there any solution without wiping out data?

Comment: Just a very stupid question: did you try to create another device through AVD? at least you would understand if the problem is just with that emulated device. In the past it happened that I had to delete a device and recreate a new one, have a try

Answer (score 0):

you should to reinstall AVD , after delete the old