# Text boxes on top of each other?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing my app and ive come across some sort of bug. On the design view of my application everything looks fine but when i run the emulator its got two of my text boxes on top of each other and im unsure of how to fixing it ?

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".Registration_form">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="298dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotellogo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_fn"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Full name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="362dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username (email)"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="285dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="239dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="507dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_room"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Room number"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
    android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

This is what it looks like:

[This is what it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onVKX.png)

Comment: Post full xml with the host layout's attributes.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry i'm new with android studio

Comment: I mean the full activity or fragment layout xml.

Comment: This is my entire xml code from it

Comment: This layout contains 5 edittexts and the 3 of them have the same id and the other 2 also the same id!!! Change the ids.

Comment: I would recommend using LinearLayout instead of relative

Comment: @forpas i've changed id names now but i have the same problem.

Comment: Post the layout as it is now.

Comment: @RicardoA. Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: @forpas I've updated it now.

Comment: @MussGench with linearlayout you don't need to worry about think kind of stuff, just need to set orientarion to vertical and it will organize the itens one above the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the attribute `android:layout_below` to position a view below another view inside a RelativeLayout.
I set the margins between the edit texts to `10dp`, you can change them if you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".Registration_form">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="298dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotellogo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_fn"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Full name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username (email)"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_room"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Room number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#E1F7F7"
        android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#807D7D"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but i have a minor problem now. When i run my emulator it says "waiting for target device to come online"

Comment: This is the emulator's issue.Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online and other answers on the same topic.