# Mac M1: App not installed on AVD when running in Android Studio

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, apple-m1

I am on a M1 Macbook Air. When I run my Android project in Android Studio it launches the AVD but my app is nowhere to be found.

I have tried this with multiple ARM api levels and different Pixel / Nexus devices but it's all the same. The AVD launches when I click the run button but my app isn't on the device. Looking in the Device File Explorer it says "waiting for authentication approval" but the AVD doesn't show any pop ups or anything asking for authentication.

Comment: Does the build log say anything?

Comment: Build output doesn't show any errors, but it says "waiting for all target devices to come online" at the bottom of the screen.  The advice here didn't make a difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online

Comment: It just so happens that the same issue happened to me 15 minutes ago - the emulator would get stuck for no reason. Wiping emulator data fixed it for me. I assume you have tried that already?

Comment: Thanks @Serge. I did try that, yes. I've just reverted to using a physical device for now and hopefully whatever this is gets fixed soon.