# Android Studio 2022.2.1 - Device Manager Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have huge problem with my Android Studio 2022 on Ubuntu 22.04.

After the upgrade i cannot run any Virtual Emulator, all are failing with the "Device Manager Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online" and when i try to stop them I have another error "An error occurred, try manually closing the Pixel 6 Pro API 32 emulator window". I tried re-installing Android Studio via apt-get, also resetting emulators, all steps are failing, desperate for help.
Screenshots of the errors below:

- An error occurred, try manually closing the Pixel 6 Pro API 32 emulator window

[image: screenshoot]

- Device Manager Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

[image: scrreenshoot]

Tried following steps to resolve:

- Reinstalling Android Studio
- Resetting emulators and download different API versions

Comment: Did you tried other emulator image other then Pixel 6 Pro API 32 ? look out for your RAM usage if tthat peaks while you are trying to run this image

Comment: See if any of the answers help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816127/waiting-for-target-device-to-come-online

Comment: @sujoybyte I tried with Nexus 6 API 31 - download it from scratch - this one is even more weird as I just see "Running devices" window without any information init

Comment: Have you tried going back to previous Android Studio version ? there is a chance that this version might have some issue in loading emulator image.. and btw what is your pc configuration ?

Comment: hey @sujoybyte the machine where i'm running Android Studio its an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, admiteddly i recently upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 which might has caused this whole mess, do you know what steps i can do to reinstall Android Studio? i did apt-get remove --purge android-studio but it did not help

Comment: If it is not removing from command line try removing it from Ubuntu's apps section, just go to **Software and Updates > Other Software**, find android studio and try to uninstall it from there. Your android studio might be installed from somewhere else like **snap** store in that case you can uninstall it by this command `sudo snap remove android-studio`

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm also on Ubuntu 22.04 and Android Studio Flamingo. The emulator used to work in these versions but today when i tried to run the emulator it just wont start. I have tried different Pixel devices and API's.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as i connect to my VPN i have no problem with the emulator launching perfectly.

I cant see anything being blocked by my firewall so i haven't been able to get to the bottom of this issue yet.